# How To Set Variables in MySQL Update Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have an estimates table, and an estimates_line_items table.  I am trying to update the estimates table whenever one it's child line items changes.  I keep running into a syntax error.  The error isn't very descriptive("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version").  It appears I am screwing up at setting the variable values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_estimate_from_line_items
AFTER UPDATE
   ON estimate_line_items FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations
   DECLARE vPrev_amnt INT;
   DECLARE vNew_amnt INT;
   DECLARE nDiff INT;

   SET vPrev_amnt = OLD.price * OLD.quantity;
   SET vNew_amnt = NEW.price * NEW.quantity;
   SET nDiff = new_amnt - prev_amnt;

   -- trigger code
   UPDATE estimates SET 
    subtotal = total + nDiff,
    total = subtotal + (tax_rate/100 * subtotal)
   WHERE estimate_id = NEW.estimate_id;

END;
```

EDIT: I've also tried setting the variables like this, with the same results:  `SET vPrev_amnt := (SELECT OLD.price * OLD.quantity);`

Comment: You've omitted the most important of the error... *for the right syntax to use near <something> at line x*.  What's the actual error?  It may not make sense to you, but I assure you it explains exactly the problem, once you understand the logic that generates the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ...

```
drop trigger if exists Update_estimate_from_line_items;
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER Update_estimate_from_line_items
AFTER UPDATE
   ON estimate_line_items FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations
   DECLARE vPrev_amnt INT;
   DECLARE vNew_amnt INT;
   DECLARE nDiff INT;


   SET vPrev_amnt = OLD.price * OLD.quantity;
   SET vNew_amnt = NEW.price * NEW.quantity;
   SET nDiff = vNew_amnt - vPrev_amnt;  -- names amended

   -- trigger code
   UPDATE estimates SET 
     subtotal = total + nDiff
   , total = subtotal + (tax_rate/100 * subtotal)
   WHERE estimate_id = NEW.estimate_id;  

END//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Might be helpful to explain what you changed outside of the code example. It took me a while to see the difference ;-) Thanks for the confirmation that this is the way to do things.